# A SqlParameter with parameter name '@name' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection function

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am trying to return a value from the code below but I am getting an error that says:

> A SqlParameter with parameter name '@vRESULT' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection

c# Code:

```
public int userLogin()
{
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ToString();
    string cmdStr = @"fucn_LOg";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = cmdStr;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            cmd.Parameters[":vResult"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("param1", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = TB_1.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("param2", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = TB_2.Text;

            cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            return Int32.Parse(cmd.Parameters[":vResult"].Value.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

the sql server function code below with returning parameter `DECLARE @vResult int`

```
CREATE FUNCTION USER_LOGIN(@USER_NAME VARCHAR(60),
                           @PWD VARCHAR(60))
RETURNS INT

AS BEGIN 

DECLARE @vResult int

SELECT @vRESULT=COUNT(*) 
    FROM OPER 
WHERE  UPPER(UNAM)=UPPER(@USER_NAME) 
   AND PSW=@PWD

IF @vResult=1
    SET @vResult=1
ELSE
    SET @vResult= -1

RETURN @vResult
END
```

Comment: You dun set any parameters named `":vResult"`. How can you assign the direction?

Comment: @Matrixta please can you explain to me more

Comment: Tell us theparameters of the `fucn_LOg` stored procedure.

Comment: You've now changed the code in your question so that *it doesn't match the error message in your title*. Since there are existing answers based on the previous, *please don't do that*. (If there hadn't been answers, it would be okay but you should make sure that your question is still *consistent*)

Answer (score 1):

Several problems.

**First**, you don't need the `cmd.Parameters.Clear();`, as you just establish a new cmd.

**Second**, use `@` for SQL Server parameters.

**Third**, a parameter named `vResult` is not set, so `cmd.Parameters[":vResult"].Direction` is invalid. You need to assign its type and value. Make sure your stored procedure has this parameter set with correct SQL data type.

**Lastly**, I guess you return the `vResult` in your stored procedure like `select @vResult;` so make it a `new vResult = function(vResult)`. But no, it is not how SQL Server work. It won't change your input parameter even though you return your `@vResult`. While, `ExecuteScaler` does. So, simply get your result back by `var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();`.

You are getting data from a stored procedure, not getting back the parameter you sent. That's the supposed correct way.

```
conn.Open();
cmd.CommandText = cmdStr;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

//Base on sql you provided, it is no need for this part.
/*
SqlParameter vResult = new SqlParameter();
vResult.ParameterName = "@vResult";
vResult.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
vResult.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.???;
vResult.Value = ???;
cmd.Parameters.Add(vResult);
*/
cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TB_1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TB_2.Text;

var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

return Int32.Parse(result.ToString());
```

Comment: I used to use this way with oracle so I get out the returning value from oracle function correct me if I am wrong `SqlParameter vResult = new SqlParameter();`  is equivalent to `cmd.Parameters.Clear();` but it clearing all parameters not only the returning parameter `@vResult` for the rest of your correction I have modified my code and update my question and add the `sql server` function... thanks for your help and please waiting for your comments

Comment: @sam, when you write `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn)`, you initiate a `SqlCommand` has no `SqlParameter` within the container `Parameters`. So there is no reason you need to clear it at all. And as the sql part you shown, you don't need to pass any `@vResult` into it, as it is created in the sql.

Comment: uh thanks ill try again with that code... since I am familiar with oracle code thinks are really totally different

Answer (score 1):

Just Get result from Stroed Procedure like this:

```
var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
return Int32.Parse(result.ToString());
```

This gets first and Only result from Stored Procedure.

Also recommend simplify your code Like this:

```
public int userLogin() {
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ToString();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("fucn_LOg", conn)) {
        try {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", TB_1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", TB_2.Text);

            var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            return Int32.Parse(result.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            return -1;
        }
        finally {
            if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed) cmd.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And your Stored procedure should looks Like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE fucn_LOg 
(
    @param1         nvarchar(max),
    @param2         nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if (exists(select * from tbUsers where flLogin = @param1 and flPassword = @param2))
    begin
        return 1;
    end
    else
    begin
        return 0;
    end
END
GO
```

OR

```
CREATE PROCEDURE fucn_LOg
(
    @param1         nvarchar(max),
    @param2         nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select COUNT(*) from tbUsers where flLogin = @param1 and flPassword = @param2    
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to debug without the SP, but a couple of things jump out.

First, you need to use the '@' character as a prefix for your parameter names, not a colon.

Second, you should define your output parameter like this:

```
SqlParameter outputParam = new SqlParameter("@vResult", SqlDbType.Int);
outputParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(outputParam);
```